# Display the result of a javascript function in a div element

Tags: javascript, html

I have a Javascript function which does the following:

- It takes the value from an list box which the user selected and assigns the value to a variable
- It then takes the number the user selected in a listbox and stores it in a variable.
- It then multiplies the value with the number to get the total
- Finally it adds 15% vat to the total
- The grand total is then displayed in an alert box

However instead of displaying the result in an alertbox I would like to display the result in an DIV element on the webpage under the form. Any ideas how I can accomplish this?

My code looks as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function calc()
{
var total = 0;
var course = 0;
var nrOfLessons = 0;
var vat = 0;

course = Number(document.getElementById("course").value)
nrOfLessons = Number(document.getElementById("nrOfLessons").value)

total =(course * nrOfLessons)
vat = total * 0.15
total = total+ vat;
window.alert(total)
}
</script>

 <form id="booking">
 <strong>COURSE: </strong>
 <select id="course">
 <optgroup label="English Courses">
 <option value="500">Beginner English</option>
 <option value="700">Mid-Level English</option>
 <option value="1000">Business English</option>
 </optgroup>
 <optgroup label="Thai Courses">
 <option value="500">Introduction to Thai</option>
 <option value="700">Pasa Thai</option>
 <option value="1000">Passa Thai Mak</option>
</optgroup>

</select>

<select id="nrOfLessons">
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option>

</select>
```

Thanx in advance for all the help

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use innerHTML

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function calc()
{
var total = 0;
var course = 0;
var nrOfLessons = 0;
var vat = 0;

course = Number(document.getElementById("course").value)
nrOfLessons = Number(document.getElementById("nrOfLessons").value)

total =(course * nrOfLessons)
vat = total * 0.15
total = total+ vat;
document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = total;
}
</script>

<div id="total"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly. One question if I may... what if I want to add text with the result. i.e i want the total displayed from the total variable with some text.

Comment: In document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = "Your Text: " +total;

Answer (score 4):

Give your `<div>` an id, such as...

```
<div id="resultDiv"></div>
```

Then in your javascript set the `.innerHTML` property...

```
document.getElementById("resultDiv").innerHTML = total.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
 <div id="resultDiv"></div>


document.getElementById("resultDiv").innerHTML = total.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#serachimg").click(function(){
    $("#search").slideToggle();
  });
});
 function content(){
    var div = document.getElementById("textDiv");
    div.textContent = "my text";
    var text = div.textContent;
 var div = document.getElementById("textDiv");
 div.style="font-size:24px";
 }
```

```html
<div id="textDiv"><script> content();</script></div>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
window.onload = function () {
var display = document.querySelector('#total');
total(display);
};

<div>The grand total is <span id="total"></span></div>
```