# How can I display a Javascript function in a DIV Tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I've created a FizzBuzz Program and now I just want to display that in a div when a button is clicked.

I've created a function which will show the div when the button is clicked. (fizzbuzzButton)

All I want it to do is display the result of the FizzBuzz Function in the Div.

Is there not a simple way to display the result of a function in a div?
Or despite that, show the result of a function after clicking a button?

I can get it to display when clicking a button using:

```
<button onclick="FizzBuzz()">Show FizzBuzz</button>
```

But when using document.write, this removes the rest of the HTML.

```html
<!DocType html>
<html>
    <body>

<script type= text/javascript>
var max = 100;

var fizz = "Fizz!";
var buzz = "Buzz!";
var fizzbuzz = "FizzBuzz!";

function FizzBuzz() {
for(var x = (1); x <= max; x++) {
    if(x % 5 == 0 && x % 3 == 0){
       document.write(fizzbuzz, "</br>" )
    }
    else if(x % 3 == 0) {
        document.write(fizz, "</br>")
    }
    else if(x % 5 == 0) {
        document.write(buzz, "</br>")
    }
    else {
        document.write(x, "</br>")
    }   
}

}

 function fizzbuzzButton() {
    document.getElementById('resultDIV').innerHTML = FizzBuzz;
}

</script>

<h1>FIZZ BUZZ!</h1>
<button onclick="fizzbuzzButton()">Show FizzBuzz</button>
<div id="resultDIV">

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `fizzbuzzButton` is not a valid function. Change your `fuzzbuzzButton` to `fizzbuzzButton` or vice versa.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display the result of a javascript function in a div element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16117290/display-the-result-of-a-javascript-function-in-a-div-element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two significant problems:

Avoid `document.write` in general; it's only useful during initial page render (which in modern workflows is basically never). Instead have your function concatenate its output into a string, and return that string; put content into the DOM using e.g. innerHTML instead of document.write.

`document.getElementById('resultDIV').innerHTML = FizzBuzz` will fill the div with the function itself.  You want to *call* the function and get its output, so use `FizzBuzz()` instead.

```js
var max = 100;

var fizz = "Fizz!";
var buzz = "Buzz!";
var fizzbuzz = "FizzBuzz!";

function FizzBuzz() {
  var output = "";
  for (var x = (1); x <= max; x++) {
    if (x % 5 == 0 && x % 3 == 0) {
      output += fizzbuzz + "<br>"
    } else if (x % 3 == 0) {
      output += fizz + "<br>"
    } else if (x % 5 == 0) {
      output += buzz + "<br>"
    } else {
      output += x + "<br>"
    }
  }
  return output;

}

function fizzbuzzButton() {
  document.getElementById('resultDIV').innerHTML = FizzBuzz();
}
```

```html
<h1>FIZZ BUZZ!</h1>
<button onclick="fizzbuzzButton()">Show FizzBuzz</button>
<div id="resultDIV">
</div>
```

(A less significant issue also changed above:  `</br>` is harmless but incorrect, use `<br>` instead.)

Comment: Perfect answer, Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

i found issue in your code and fixed for you, created one jsfiddle, have a look 
This will help you
https://jsfiddle.net/wnx50hfr/

```
<!DocType html>
<html>
    <body>

<script type= text/javascript>
var max = 100;

var fizz = "Fizz!";
var buzz = "Buzz!";
var fizzbuzz = "FizzBuzz!";

function FizzBuzz() {
for(var x = (1); x <= max; x++) {
    if(x % 5 == 0 && x % 3 == 0){
       document.write(fizzbuzz, "</br>" )
    }
    else if(x % 3 == 0) {
        document.write(fizz, "</br>")
    }
    else if(x % 5 == 0) {
        document.write(buzz, "</br>")
    }
    else {
        document.write(x, "</br>")
    }   
}

}

 function fizzbuzzButton() {
    document.getElementById('resultDIV').innerHTML = FizzBuzz;
}

</script>


<h1>FIZZ BUZZ!</h1>
<button onClick="fizzbuzzButton()">Show FizzBuzz</button>
<div id="resultDIV">

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's also always a good idea to include some explanation of your answer, so people can see what you changed and why; as far as I can tell this code is identical to that in the question (and has the same errors).

Answer (score 0):

1. Only function `fuzzbuzzButton` is declared, and there is no `fizzbuzzButton` function.
2. If you want to run the function, you should use `FizzBuzz()` and not `FizzBuzz`.

Replace the function with

```
function fizzbuzzButton() {
    document.getElementById('resultDIV').innerHTML = FizzBuzz;
}
```

If you want to write to the div with id 'resultDIV' through your approach, you should rather get the result as a string, and assign it to `document.getElementById('resultDIV').innerHTML`.